# Project with .NET Core 8 SDK Didn't Show Views

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I installed .NET 8 SDK and all my ASP.NET Core projects and solutions don't run properly and I get this error that views not found.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable originalLocations)

When I uninstalled .NET 8 SDK, all of the project works properly.

Comment: Are you using MVC or razor pages?

Comment: What is your version of VisualStudio? Can you provide a .NET version where you can run your project? Or provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: What is your project .net version. did you upgrade your project then test it or just install on your pc and this didn't work?

Comment: I use MVC with visual studio 17.7.2 - the version of all of my projects is under 8

Comment: You can try go update your visual studio version to 17.8 .